# Is it possible to change the Menu in real time?

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, layout-inflater

Depending on whatever arbitrary criteria I decide, is it possible to change the contents of the Menu (the triple-dot thing you click in the upper right, which drops down whatever settings you'd like to include).

Can this be done? Right now I don't know how to because I see lines like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and I don't know if I can "re-inflate" the menu in real time / change the options / etc.

Comment: have you read [Changing menu items at runtime](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu) from the Android docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the way I do it:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       if(condition1){
           MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
           inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_1, menu);
       }else{ 
           MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
           inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_2, menu);
       }
       return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [you can](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu). The main idea is that you get the instance of `MenuInflater` via `getMenuInflater()` then inflate your menu XML. It's not restricted on your Activity/Fragment's `onCreateOptionsMenu()` or `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

Also, it doesn't have to be hidden on the triple dot-menu or overflow menu. There's a configuration for when you want it to be hidden on the overflow menu or shown all the time via `showAsAction`.